# Как добавить данные в json файл не перетирая те данные, что там находятся?

Tags: php, json

Используя функцию fwrite(), наткнулся на одну проблему - те данные, что находились в файле заменяются новыми. Что нужно использовать для добавления новых данных в файл? Может нужно использовать другую функцию, по типу file_put_contents?
Вот код пхп:

**post.php**

```
<?php
$ID = $_POST['pseudoID'];
$arr = $_POST;
unset($arr['pseudoID']);
$fullArray = array(
    "pseudoID" => $ID,
    "data" => array($arr)
);
$fullArray = json_encode($fullArray);
$file = fopen('token_data.json', 'w+');
fwrite($file,$fullArray);
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: Если данные не находятся в структуре JSON файла, то ответ ниже вам подойдёт. В противном случае вам придется распарсивать JSON данные файла, вставлять куда нужно и сериализовать обратно в файл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас в файле находится JSON и вы хотите добавить каки-либо данные в него, то можно сделать так:

```php
$initialData = ['a' => 1];

file_put_contents('test.json', json_encode($initialData));

$savedData = json_decode(file_get_contents('test.json'), true);

$savedData['b'] = 2;

file_put_contents('test.json', json_encode($savedData));
```

- https://replit.com/@w3lifer/WoodenInterestingPatches#main.php
- https://php.net/file-put-contents

---

Если вы хотите просто добавить данные в конец файла, то можно опять же использовать `file_put_contents()` с флагом `FILE_APPEND`:

```php
file_put_contents('test.txt', '1' . "\n");
file_put_contents('test.txt', '2' . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

- https://replit.com/@w3lifer/NecessaryLightcoralLight#main.php

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы добавить новые данные, не перетирая старые, необходимо открыть файл в режиме записи, используя аргумент a+, который перемещает указатель в конец файла.

```
$file = fopen('token_data.json', 'a+');
```